# What manufacturers make linux based WiFi routers or ADSL modems?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, hardware-rec

Do companies make linux based wifi routers or ADSL modems? If yes, what are these companies?

Comment: Are you asking what companies makes "open" Linux routers (easy to hack), or are you asking how popular Linux is amongst the router makers?

Comment: First option: I'm interested in open, customizable routers with open linux distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

buy one of these: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices
Put this on it: http://www.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv3/community/developmentnews.html

This will give you a linux router. :)

Answer (score 2):

Linksys is known do make [Linux based routers](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7322), and other Linux based devices.

Answer (score 2):

The OpenWRT project has a hardware compatibility list. If it's in there, then linux can at least be installed on it, but most (all?) of them run some version of linux pre-installed. See http://oldwiki.openwrt.org/TableOfHardware.html

Answer (score 0):

ASUS

- [site with custom firmwares](http://www.wl500g.info/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, most companies use some sort of Linux for their routers. I know for sure DLink have linux on my DSL-604GT+.