# (Linux hackable router) What hardware + software?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I read [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/24099/) on Linux-based wifi routers, and I'd like to check what my options are.

I'm looking for 1) an affordable wifi router that 2) can be reflashed with Linux to provide load balancing (so VoIP is usable even when I'm downloading a big file) + can act as a wifi bridge between a laptop and a remote wifi router with a weak signal + supports 802.11n.

I have a couple of questions:

1. I guess the venerable Linksys WRT54 series is on its way out, so at this point, what modern hardware should I get?
2. Are there other open-source Linux projects besides OpenWRT and DD-WRT that I should know about?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative firmware is [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato). It has [Quality of Service (QOS)](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Tomato_%28firmware%29/Menu_Reference#QoS_.E2.80.94_Quality_of_Service) settings which will handle your requirement for VoIP quality.

Hardware options for 802.11n seem limited or non-existent. One option would be to have a linux (Tomato, DD-WRT, whatever) router connected to your broadband line and then have a 802.11n wireless access point on a wired connection to your linux router.

Update: Here's a [blog post](http://markedeyoung.blogspot.com/2009/03/openwrt-supported-80211n-routers.html) with news about 802.11n support in Open-WRT.

Comment: 802.11n finally has a published standard as of this week, so perhaps we'll see more options in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

You could get an [LaFonera 2](http://www.fon.com/en/) (n capable in the US, as far as I know) and try to [hack](http://www.hackafon.com/) it. The router itself is quite capable even without hacking, I think.

I don't know about the bridging, though. You'll need 2 antennas for that, don't you?

Concerning the distribution: there are some spin-offs of dd-wrt/openwrt, which may offer some additional stuff easier, but you'll get along with these two, I think.

Answer (score 0):

- Recent discussion here on bridging with a Linux router

  - [Using wifi router as bridge to increase signal](https://superuser.com/questions/41204/using-wifi-router-as-bridge-to-increase-signal)
- You could even get an old PC with a WiFi card hooked for the purpose,

  - [Linux LiveCD Router](http://www.wifi.com.ar/english/cdrouter/) (is one reference)

    - can even boot your PC from a USB Flash
    - have not checked for bridging support explicitly,
      but, looking at the feature-set, bridging is likely to be supported too